# raise two exceptions for one test

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, selenium-webdriver, nunit

here is my same selenium webdriver with c# code.
I am validating 2 functionality in the same test.

I want to raise separate exceptions for test case1 and test case2.

so if,
         `Assert.IsTrue(driver.IsElementPresent(By.LinkText("Help")));` fails, i want raise a exception in which i will update my test tool that test case1 has failed.

and if either one of 
          `driver.FindElement(driver.IsElementPresent(By.LinkText("Ok")).Click();
            Assert.IsTrue(driver.IsElementPresent(By.LinkText("Logged In")));`
fails, i want to update my tool that test case2 has failed by sending it to a different exception.

Any help on this would be appreciated.... any idea on handling this with a single exception is also fine.

```
    [Test]
    public void TestTwo()
    {
        try
        {
    //open Page

            // test case 1
            Assert.IsTrue(driver.IsElementPresent(By.LinkText("Help")));

            // test case 2
            driver.FindElement(driver.IsElementPresent(By.LinkText("Ok")).Click();
            Assert.IsTrue(driver.IsElementPresent(By.LinkText("Logged In")));
        }


        catch (Exception e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("FAILED");
        }


    }
```

Comment: `I am validating 2 functionality in the same test` is your first issue, break this into separate tests. Also, why do you think you should catch and handle the exception thrown by an assertion failure?

Comment: i dont want to run it twice..and this is a small example i provided in the code above, to reach test case1, it takes about 3 mins... so in-order to run test case2 which starts off from where test case 1 left off, i would need to rerun those 3 mins of test
i want to handle exceptions because, i need to update pass/ fail results in my test case repository tool for the test case,.. so if test case 1 fails, in exception 1 i tell it to change the status as failse  .. likewise for exception2 as well

Comment: This is really unclear, and I agree with the comments, they are fundamentally two different test cases, so they need to be two different test methods. Your code, just like the application code, should be well written and follow standards like the KISS principle too! Give us a real life example to help us understand this. What should happen to the test when your first assertion fails? Does the test stop? Should it stop as a fail? As a pass?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to distinguish which of the two cases fails in your test run report.

The easiest way that comes to my mind is to use failure messages as second parameter for your `Assert`s.

```
// test case 1
Assert.IsTrue(driver.IsElementPresent(By.LinkText("Help")), "help link is missing");

// test case 2
Assert.IsTrue(driver.IsElementPresent(By.LinkText("Logged In")), "user is not logged in");
```